# How to indirectly convert Monero to Ethereum in MetaMask?

Tags: metamask, wallets, exchanges, defi, privacy

Obviously MetaMask only deals in ERC-20 tokens, which means MetaMask doesn't recognize Monero, but **indirectly**, how can one send/swap/convert Monero funds to an Ethereum hot wallet?

The idea is to load crypto into an Ethereum hot wallet, not by sending funds in from a crypto exchange which can be traced back to the exchange, but have the funds *swapped in* from an untraceable source. Any alternative, similar approaches would be helpful.